# JQuery Ajax Challenge - Build an object from SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint

**Overview**:  I'm trying to build a dynamic auto-complete list for a textbox based upon data in a SharePoint list.

*What works:*

```
function GetAccounts()
   {
   var call = $.ajax({ 
   url: 
            "../_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Plans')/items?$select=Title,Account&$orderby=Title asc", 
            type: "GET", 
            dataType: "json", 
            headers: { 
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" 
            } 
        }); 
        call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){ 
         var table = $('#results1').dataTable({ 
                           "aaData": data.d.results, 
                           "aoColumns": [ 
                                { "mData": "Title", "sClass": "dt-center","sTitle": "Plan Name" }, 
                                { "mData": "Account","sClass": "dt-center", "sTitle": "Account",
                                "mRender": function (data, type, full) { 
                                stemp = {
                                    label: full.Title + ' (' + full.Account + ')',
                                    value: full.Account
                                }
                                    source.push(stemp);
                                    return data;
                                }
                                }       
                            ]
                        }); 


        }
        );
   }
```

This is great but I have no need for a data table.  How do I lose the table but still populate the *stemp* object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Here is my working function:

```
function GetAccounts()
    {
       var call = $.ajax({ 
            url: 
            "../_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Plans')/items?$select=Title,Account&$Top=3500&$orderby=Title asc", 
            type: "GET", 
            dataType: "json", 
            headers: { 
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" 
            } 
        }); 
        call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){ 
            for(var i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++){
                var result = data.d.results[i];
                var suggestion = {
                    label:  result.Title + ' (' + result.Account + ')',
                    value: result.Account
                };
                source.push(suggestion);
                }

        }
        );


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are actually asking for. However, maybe something like this could work.

Assuming you are using Autocomplete plugin for jQuery, you can try this (note - the code is untested):

```
$("#autoComplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        var term = request.term; // get what user has typed into the text box
        var call = $.ajax({
            url: "../_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Plans')/items"+
               +"?$select=Title,Account&$orderby=Title asc"
               +"&filter=startswith(Title, @term) or startswith(Account, @term)&@term='"+term+"'", 
            type: "GET", 
            dataType: "json", 
            headers: { 
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" 
            } 
        }); 

        call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
            var dataToSuggest = [];
            var results = data.d.results;
            for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++){
                var result = result[i];
                var suggestion = {
                    label:  result.Title + ' (' + result.Account + ')',
                    value: result.Account
                };
                dataToSuggest.push(suggestion);
            }
            // call the response callback of the autocomplete with single value - items to be suggested
            response(dataToSuggest);  
        }
        );

    }

});
```

You initiate the plugin on the input by calling `autocomplete` function, passing options.
Options object has one key, `source` which indicates how the autocomplete will get it suggestions.

According to documentation, `source` can be a function. This function takes two arguments - `request` which has the term that user had typed into the input field and `response` - a callback that takes one argument - data that should be presented to user as options he can choose from.

We extract the term that has been supplied by the user and use it as parameter to filter out the items on the list. We do that by passing the value of the term into the `$filter` clause of the OData query.

When the call is executed and finished, we take the data returned from list and build an objects for the autocomplete, using `label` and value `fields` - this will allow to render the friendly string and use the account as value when selected.

After we have the item created, we push that into the array - `dataToSuggest`. After all items have been processed, we can call the `response` callback using the suggestions array we created as the parameter, and autocomplete should display you the choices.

As I said, code is untested and might need some tweaking, but I hope it will help you getting started. I used Autocomplete jQueryUI plugin documentation as source.

[jQueryUI Autocomplete plugin documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: I would appreciate if you could upvote my answer and consider accepting it.